# Vim syntax highlighting unwanted words

Tags: vim, syntax, highlight

I have created a syntax file for some AnB-files for vim and while it does load the syntax highlighting and highlight everything I want it to highlight, it seems to highlight some unwanted stuff as well.

The images show both my highlight file and the AnB file and the problem is:
The word "Elgamel", the characters "g" and "h" (any single lower-case letters) and the words "M1" and "M2" (any single upper-case letter followed by an integer) are highlighted with an unwanted magenta color. Anyone knows what to do here? I tried searching for the problem on both google and stackoverflow, but I couldn't find any similar questions (I might not search using the correct terms, though :D)

Syntax file: https://i.stack.imgur.com/4ocL1.png

AnB file: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pk7ft.png

Comment: Can you include the syntax highlighting code in your question?

Comment: just a guess, did you define some spell-check rules? does it look different if you `set nospell`? it looks like the error highlight. btw, the WM is nice, is it awesome? ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks like error highlighting from the spell checker.

```
:set nospell
```

should then turn it off. You can determine which syntax groups get spell checked via `:syntax spell`, see `:help :syn-spell`. Usually, you use enable spelling in comments, etc. by added `contains=@Spell`.

---

Here's a tip for syntax script development: When you need to find out which syntax group causes the highlighting. `:syn list` shows all active groups, but it's easier when you install the [SyntaxAttr.vim - Show syntax highlighting attributes of character under cursor](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=383) plugin.

Comment: Thanks a ton! It was indeed spell checking!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the plugin [HiKinkTrace](https://github.com/gerw/vim-HiLinkTrace) to determine the highlighting group for the offending text, that should help you to narrow it down.